#  java.lang.NullPointerException 

Tags: android

CustomDialogExample.java

```
public class CustomDialogExample extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           /** Display Custom Dialog */
           CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(this);
           customizeDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

---

CustomizeDialog.java

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Button okButton;

public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
super(context);
/** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
/** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
setContentView(R.layout.main1);
okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
/** When OK Button is clicked, dismiss the dialog */
if (v == okButton)
dismiss();
}

}
```

this is code of my activity to which i want to call from service ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have CustomDialogExample activity mentioned in your AndroidManifest.xml, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".CustomDialogExample" android:label="Dialog Example"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: @vladimir i am not getting!!should i told you whole my application flow or what?please tell me......

Comment: @Vladimir Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.CustomDialogExample}: java.lang.NullPointerException
i got this error ..

Comment: You have NPE in your activity. Check the code of it please. If you fail to do this update the question with excepption details and the code of onCreate of your activity.

Comment: @Vladimir hi...i have edited the Q. and i have put my Activity code to which i want to call from service...so,please help me to remove this error..

Comment: I afraid you don't build your dialog correctly. See how it is done with standard Alert dialog. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: @Vladimir how i have created dialog,i have written the code of that,actually i have written another activity for it.....please see it.....n help me to remove error......

Comment: okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
okButton.setOnClickListener(this); - here is the problem. Ensure that findViewById returns you not null.

Comment: @Vladimir i checked there is no null value in findViewById.

Comment: please, put the numbers on your lines and tell me what line do you get NullPointerException at.